# Meaning of name attribute in JBoss MBean xml descriptor

Tags: jboss, jmx, mbeans

JBoss 4/5 MBeans such as NamingAlias are defined in XML as follows

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.naming.NamingAlias" name=":service=NamingAlias,fromName=queue/original">
    <attribute name="ToName">queue/linked</attribute>
    <attribute name="FromName">queue/original</attribute>
</mbean>
```

Paying attention to the attribute`name=":service=NamingAlias,fromName=queue/original` I see the parameters `service` and `fromName`.

Following the instructions to create a custom MBean here:

https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ExampleHelloWorldService

The XML configuration for the MBean created is

```
<server>
  <mbean code="com.acme.HelloWorldService" name="acme.com:service=HelloWorld">
    <attribute name="Message">Hello World</attribute>
  </mbean>
</server>
```

I noticed only `service` is specified in the name attribute.

Is service mandatory for all the beans? What about adding additional parameters such as fromName? Can these values be used from within the class that implements the MBean or are those mandated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **name** attribute can be any valid (and unique) JMX [ObjectName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/ObjectName.html). The keys and values themselves do not have any special significance other than their subjective significance to the developer.

In the first example, the ObjectName does not specify a domain (the value to the left of the colon) so the MBeanServer assumes the default domain, which in this case would be **jboss** so notionally:

```
:service=NamingAlias,fromName=queue/original  ==  jboss:service=NamingAlias,fromName=queue/original
```

The ObjectName (and it's embedded domain and key/values) can be used within the class. In standard JMX, one would typically make the impl implement [MBeanRegistration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanRegistration.html) which injects the MBeanServer and ObjectName when the bean is registered. However, the example you referenced is a specialized JBoss [ServiceMBean](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/org/jboss/system/ServiceMBean.java.html) which does this automatically and your implementation will store the ObjectName in the field called **serviceName**.